# Modal not shown while clicking the button in BootStrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Have a look at the below code:

```
<div class="loginPanel">
    <div class="myFormContainer">
        <div class="myPanelHeadingContainer">
            <h3 class="myPanelTitle">
              Login
            </h3>
            <span id="flipper1">
              <a href="#">Register</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="myPanelBody">
            <form id="loginForm">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="authCode">Authentication Code</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="authCode" placeholder="Auth code" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loadingModal">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="registerPanel">
        <div class="myFormContainer">
            <div class="myPanelHeadingContainer">
                <h3 class="myPanelTitle">
                  Register
                </h3>
                <span id="flipper2">
                  <a href="#">Login</a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="myPanelBody">
                <form id="registerForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Your name here" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="newAuthCode">New Authentication Code</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="newAuthCode" placeholder="New auth code" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="clientSecret">Client Secret</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="clientSecret" placeholder="Client secret" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loadingModal">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="sk-fading-circle">
                  <div class="sk-circle1 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle2 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle3 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle4 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle5 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle6 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle7 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle8 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle9 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle10 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle11 sk-circle"></div>
                  <div class="sk-circle12 sk-circle"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As, you can see..the modal is expected to pop when submit button is clicked in either form. But When I click the submit button in the Login form, nothing happens. I know I have made some mistakes because it was working properly a few hours back then I don't know what I did wrong and now my code is completely broken. The modal window is there to show a loading spinner. In the above code, you can see an anchor element in each Form with text Register and Login respectively. I don't know if it's necessary but I will explain what it does. I want to hide the Login form and show the registration form when Register link is clicked. The registration form also has a button in same manner which hides itself and brings the Login form in visual. The registration form also has a submit button which when clicked, fires the modal.

As I mentioned above, the modal is not popping when submit button from the Login form is clicked. But when I switch to registration form and click Submit there, it fires the modal. The more interesting thing is that when I switch back to the Login form and click submit there, it also shows the modal as expected. In short when the URL changes to myfile.php?#, everything works fine but when it is myfile.php or myfile.php?, I can't fire the Modal from Login form's submit button without switching the form for at least once.

Comment: if you use $("#loadingModal").show() in Google console; does it open your modal ?

Comment: Do you mean google chrome console?

Comment: I tried in browser based console. It returns some kind of guy bject.

Comment: make a screen ;)

Comment: if "guy bject" appears in console it means you don't have bootstrap loaded in page :D I think

Comment: In this page, press F5, go to console, type: $("#question-header").show()     if a new "guy bject" is shown then yes boostrap library is missing

Comment: btw use $("#oadingModal").modal() instead of $("#loadingModal").show()

Answer (score 0):

Below code will launch modal window on button click. 
This is not the code that makes your logic to work but this will just pop up the modal window on button click. 
**Libraries used:** jquery 2.1.1, Bootstrap 3.3.7

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**Reference:** https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Answer (score 0):

Give some time to submit the form and to show modal

you are doing same thing at same time, First show the modal and then submit the form

```js
function myFunction()
{

  setTimeout(function(){
              
              $("#loginForm").submit(); // if you want            
          }, 2000);


  return false;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  <div class="loginPanel">
    <div class="myFormContainer">
        <div class="myPanelHeadingContainer">
            <h3 class="myPanelTitle">
              Login
            </h3>
            <span id="flipper1">
              <a href="#">Register</a>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="myPanelBody">
            <form id="loginForm"  >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="authCode">Authentication Code</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="authCode" placeholder="Auth code" />
                </div>
                <button onclick="return myFunction();" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loadingModal">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="modal fade" id="loadingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
             <div class="modal-content">

             loading

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```